# How to change values inside if statements, determined by user input

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm attempting to make a program where a person inputs their salary and number of hours worked and the output will be their net pay, tax deducted and gross pay.
The individuals tax rate and pay rate(per hour) will be determined by their annual salary.
Examples:

Annual Salary $0 - $16,500 : Tax rate is 11.32%, Pay rate is $8.68 per hour
Annual Salary $16,501 - $19,500 : Tax rate is 15.14%, Pay rate is $10.26 per hour

There are about 8 different options similar to the ones shown above. My first question is how do I declare the variables of TAX_RATE and PAY_RATE, before I start determining what each of them will equal. I wasn't sure what I would add as a value after I declared them.

```
float TAX_RATE = 
float PAY_RATE =
```

An example of my attempt at an if statement is shown below, but I get an error saying that it would give different meaning to TAX_RATE and PAY_RATE

```
if (annual_salary >= 00 && annual_salary <= 16500)
        {
            float TAX_RATE = 11.32F;
            float PAY_RATE = 8.68F;
        }
```

So here for example, if the person has an annual salary of $15000, their pay rate and tax would be 11.32% and $8.68per hour, respectively.

How would i go about declaring the variables and then being able to manipulate them depending on the user's input?

ADDON: When i'm doing the equations to calculate the gross pay and tax, it gives me the message "USE OF UNASSIGNED LOCAL VARIABLE (TAX_RATE, PAY_RATE)"

```
 gross_pay = hours_worked * PAY_RATE;
 tax = gross_pay * (TAX_RATE / 100);
```

Comment: simply do float taxRate; and taxRate = 11.32;

Comment: ok that was a lot simpler than i though, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare them outside the `if` statements like this, and assign them inside:

```
float TAX_RATE;
float PAY_RATE;

if (annual_salary >= 00 && annual_salary <= 16500)
{
    TAX_RATE = 11.32F;
    PAY_RATE = 8.68F;
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks i've just got an addon question if you guys could have a look at it.

Comment: @user3687717: You don't have an `else` branch I think thus the variable `TAX_RATE` has no value set. Create an `else` branch or make sure the other `if` statements always lead to assigning the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `float` **inside** the if-statement. Do it before that `if`

Answer (score 1):

Well as per my understanding of your question you want variables which are default declared and then you want to change its values so go for below process:

```
float TAX_RATE = 0;
float PAY_RATE = 0;

if (annual_salary >= 00 && annual_salary <= 16500)
{
    TAX_RATE = 11.32F;
    PAY_RATE = 8.68F;
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think stating the floats with an = 0, has fixed my addon problem.

Comment: @user3687717: It might, but be aware that there might be a hole in your logic if it wasn't assigned.